# hogan.js + jade?

Tags: javascript, templates, node.js, mustache, pug

I want to use hogan.js but I currently write all my html in jade. How could I set up a workflow that would allow me to write templates in jade but still compile them with hogan?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: lol wut? hogan.js is a different templating engine with a _DIFFERENT TEMPLATING LANGUAGE_. Port your templates.

Comment: @Raynos Actually you're wrong, you can use jade to write the html for your hogan templates, like i am now, and like the question asked. thanks!

Comment: @boom, how did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you speak, you want to build two sets of templates, one in the server and one client. To do this, the client templates are written in Jade. That is so

```
script#myTempate( type="template/hogan" )
    .timeline
        //load more button
        button {{message}}
        // tweet object
        | {{#tweets}}
        |   {{> tweet}}
        | {{/tweets}}
```

And it's the only way to mix these templating systems